# What do you call the area of a park that has children's play equipment?

Tags: single-word-requests, american-english

I'm looking for a word or phrase to describe the area of the park that has swingsets, jungle gyms, and other sorts of children's play equipment.

"They went to the [word or phrase] to go play on the jungle gym."

Comment: Could you add a geographic tag, this probably varies across the anglosphere.

Comment: In the US it's pretty much always called a "playground".

Comment: UK here, I’d call it the "play park". Or "the swings". Usually a swing is the bare minimum.

Comment: in my neck of the woods, within a school 'playground' we'd call that subjection with equipment 'the play structures' .  But at the park, 'plaground' would be that subsection.  I would not be surprised if there are regional differences though.

Comment: @Pam Ha, the reason I asked for a geographic tag was for the use of ‘play area’ vs ‘play park’ in the UK

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**playground**

An outdoor area provided for children to play in, especially at a school or public park.

[source](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/playground)